# Unexpected values while reading wav blocks in C++

Tags: c++, wav

I have a what seems to be an easy problem yet I can't seem to get the results I want.

According to the [Wav Format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/), a 16-bit wav file is signed and values range from  -32768 to 32767. Yet I can only seem to be getting positive integers, what am I missing?

Here's a screenshot of the few bits of data I outputted:

[image: Ran Program]
[image: Wav Hex Values]

- Additionally, can someone explain how to tell apart the right channel data and left channel data? I can't seem to find enough examples of this. Thanks.

Here's the code I used, `wav.getFile()` returns the file pointer exactly after reading all the other header data.

```
int SoundData;

        for( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
        {

            fread( &SoundData, 4, 1, wav.getFile() );
            cout << SoundData << endl;
        }
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: The `int` type is 32-bit, and when reading a 16-bit number into that you won't get automatic sign extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does changing `SoundData` to a `short int` help?

Comment: Or explicitly using `signed int`?

Comment: Also, you're reading 4 bytes at a time ... don't you want to read 2 bytes at a time (16 bits)?

Comment: Well spotted - didn't see that.

Comment: Thanks, this along Jeroen's answer helped. However I did have another question on how to tell which samples are right or left channel.

Comment: @john I had already included this question in my original question, doesn't that count? It didn't seem like a 'big' enough of a question to post separately since it's also part of how I'm trying to read the data. However if you really think it should go as a separate question I'll reconsider moving it to as a new question.

Comment: @Tek Sorry missed that, but maybe others have too?

Comment: @john I think I'll take you up on moving it as new question since everyone seems to have left now that there's answers :P

Answer (score 0):

(going to put this as answer suggestion):

You're reading 4 bytes at a time ... don't you want to read 2 bytes at a time (16 bits)?

so

```
fread( &SoundData, 4, 1, wav.getFile() );
```

should become

```
fread( &SoundData, 2, 1, wav.getFile() );
```

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood. The specification said "2's complement signed integers" and somehow I understood it as "2 byte complimented signed integers" aka combined. :x Thanks!